# Implementing three-layer architecture in FastAPI for handling endpoints that need multiple services, better to create own service?

Tags: python, rest, architecture, fastapi

I have a question regarding the three-layer architecture implementation in FastAPI. Consider a complex scenario: let's say there's an endpoint called 'get_transaction'. The data required for this transaction encompasses information from a user, a product, and a sale. Each of these entities has its own service.

My question is, what would be the appropriate approach?

**Option 1**: In the application layer (where the endpoint is defined), I call these three services individually and construct the 'transactionDto' object, which is then sent.

**Option 2**: I create a 'transactionService' that invokes these three services and builds a 'transaction' object. This object is then sent back to the application layer, which subsequently sends it to the user. (This involves calls between services)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, it's the existence of an identity that defines whether this is it's own restful service, or whether it falls more into a [BFF](https://medium.com/mobilepeople/backend-for-frontend-pattern-why-you-need-to-know-it-46f94ce420b0)/Aggregation type service.  It ultimately doesn't matter that much, having services call other services is fine, but it helps to logically separate out things that have their own storage/identity as a different class of service for scalability and management sake.

Comment: I believe I am closely following the REST guidelines. Each of my services references an entity. The inter-service calls I typically use are solely for validating constraints (e.g., creating a transaction with a product_id, checking if the product referenced by product_id exists and is active). However, I think you mean that if I create a service for a non-existent entity, as I mentioned (transaction), it would deviate from following REST rules. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: If Transaction is a common resource that means something specifically, create a service/function to compose it properly from the other service, don't do it inline in your controller. You can define a dependency in FastAPI as requiring other dependencies. Do whatever makes it as clear as possible and contains the responsibility in a single location.

Comment: Any book or documentation where i can read more of that?